# OR and AND functions in java?

Tags: java, logic

What are the `OR` and `AND` operators in Java? I've tried `or`, `system.or`, and all sorts of stuff, but haven't found anything.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn: Probably not, since Google would interpret OR and AND as search operators.

Comment: Try to be less ambiguous with your searches. "Java or" would've given you exactly what you wanted in the first result.

Comment: @Boann Google is much smarter than that.

Comment: Did you consider reading the documentation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well let me break it up for you..........

**Short Circuit `And` & `Or` operator:**

**AND Gate :** `&&`

**OR Gate  :** `||`

**Non-Short Circuit `And` & `Or` operator:**

**AND Gate :** `&`

**OR Gate  :** `|`

**Difference between Short and Non-Short Circuit Operator:**

`if (false && true)`  **// As the 1st statement is false it won't evaluate the 2nd condition**

`if (false & true)` **//Even though the 1st statement is false, it will still evaluate the 2nd condition**

Answer (score 3):

Um, what do you mean by "logic gates"?  Do you mean [`||` and `&&`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html)?

Answer (score 3):

`||` is what you use for OR.

`&&` is what you use for AND.

Answer (score 1):

Check Summary of Operators @ Oracle

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html

Answer (score 0):

and is && and or is ||
See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `|| which is OR` and `&& which is AND` operators?

Answer (score 0):

Or -> ||
And -> &&

As an example 
    if a == 1 and b == 2 -> if (a == 1 && b == 2)

Answer (score 0):

there have to import logicgate.*
is should able to let the program use AND , OR , and NOT gate (not sure for others)

example :

create variable using AND class and 2 extra variable for process

```
 And and = new And();
 int no1 = 10 , no2 = 20;
```

next, do the process using AND gate logic

```
 int answer = and.doOperation(no1,no2);
```

same workflow using others logic gates